# parse xml that contain colon

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have this XML text:

```
<test:solution xmlns:test="http://www.test.com/">
    <script/>
    <test:question>
        <test:param name="name1">value 1</test:param>
        <test:param name="name2"> value 2</test:param>
    </test:question>
</test:solution>
```

when I run my application that contains those lines:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlUrl);
XmlNode testQuestions = doc.SelectSingleNode("/test:solution/test:question");
//XmlNodeList testParamNodeList = testQuestions.SelectNodes("test:param");
```

It give an error, I know that the error come from the *colons*, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Thanks for help

Comment: What error do you get? The colon separates the namespace from the element name.

Comment: You need to add (define) the `test` namespace for this to work.

Comment: Those *colon* really are **XML namespaces** and you should read up on them to understand what they are and how to deal with them! Google or Bing will help you find the necessary information

Comment: I don't know how XmlDocument handle namespaces in my case, an example would be very useful

Comment: Please don't tell us that something gives an error without telling us what the error is. It's like telling your doctor that you are in  pain and not telling them where it hurts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

    doc.Load(PATH);

    XmlNamespaceManager ns = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
    ns.AddNamespace("test", "http://www.test.com/");
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("//test:solution//test:question", ns);
```